# Thread.currentThread in case of parallel threads

Tags: java, multithreading

Current implementation of Thread.sleep is:

```
public static void sleep(long millis) throws InterruptedException {
    if (millis < 0L) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("timeout value is negative");
    } else {
        Thread var3 = currentThread();
.....
```

currentThread is native method.
In a multi-core system we can have multiple threads actually running at same time.

How is current thread then decided?

Comment: Threads run instructions and are mapped to cores. One thread is associated with at most one core at any one point in time. Therefore, each instruction is associated with exactly on e thread. Each instruction is executed on exactly one core, therefore bound to exactly one thread. `Thread.currentThread()` is the thread that executes the current statement (or thread of executions, to be precise).

Comment: it is just the same `Thread` that is calling the `sleep` method (this is not necessarily related (directly) to any core)

Comment: The call to method `currentThread()` is executed on a specific thread, that thread is identified through native code and returned.

Comment: You might want to look at how threading is implemented for a given OS (e.g. libc in Linux).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Current thread" does not mean what you think it means. What it means is, the thread that called the `Thread.currentThread()` function. The name is left over from ancient times when computers only had one CPU each. In those days, only one thread could be "current," and so the thread that called the function and the current thread were one and the same.

Comment: "The name is left over from ancient times when computers only had one CPU each." - I find the name `currentThread` to be perfectly applicable to the multicore too. E.g. it is the "thread which currently executes our code". It describes the **multithreading** aspect, not a multicore one.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, Sure, but which thread is "current" when multiple threads currently are executing our code? Depends what you think "current" means. A name like `Thread.self()` would have caused less confusion. But the original authors of the Java language were some pretty smart dudes. If they didn't think of it at the time, then I can't pretend that I would have thought of it back then either.

Comment: P.S., where the name _really_ comes from: In a single-CPU OS, there would have been a variable in the kernel code that pointed to the context record for the thread that currently was being executed by the CPU. The variable would have a name like `current_thread`, and the system call that a user-mode function could call to find out the identity of the thread that was executing it was pretty much just a "getter" for that kernel variable.

Comment: "A name like `Thread.self()` would have caused less confusion." - Assuming a `Thread` is a threading **library**, and not a representation of the specific thread, I find the method `.self` even more confusing (as pointing to the library, not to the thread). Actually, I don't think that there is a name which would represent a conception of the "current thread" in non-confusing way. But "Current Thread" is de-facto a standard name for the concept, and it is used in many programming languages.